# grep not giving expected result

Tags: unix, grep

I am having trouble understanding following `grep` operation

```
a=jQuery.Uno
echo $a | grep -i "jquerya*"
```

why is above query returning  `jQuery.Uno`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` quantifier matches 0 (zero) or more.

In the string, `jQuery.Uno` there is 0 `a` after `y`.  As such, the regex `jquerya*` matches the string.

If you wanted one or more of `a`, then instead say:

```
grep -i "jquerya\{1,\}"
```

or, if your version of `grep` supports extended regular expressions:

```
grep -iE "jquerya+"
```

---

Moreover, instead of `echo "$var" | grep ...`, it is better to make use of herestrings if your shell supports those:

```
grep -iE "jquerya+" <<< "$a"
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for fixing the typos.